# elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create elasticsearch query and apply filter on search result as below:

```
"query" : {
        "custom_filters_score" : {
            "query" : {"match" : {"country" : {"query" : "usa","operator" : "and"}}},
            "filters" : [
                {
                    "filter" : {"query" : {"match" : {"state" : {"query" : "statename","operator" : "and"}}} },
                    "boost" : "3"
                },
                {
                    "filter" : {"query" : {"match" : {"city" : {"query" : "cityname","operator" : "and"}}} },
                    "boost" : "3"
                }
            ],
            "score_mode" : "first"
        }
    }
```

Here filters are not working. It is not filtering data for specific state and city and returning data for all state and city for country usa.

Any help please!

Regards

Comment: May I know if my answer helped?

Comment: @javanna Yes your answer helped me. I studied and used Normal filer and it works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood what the [Custom Filter Score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-filters-score-query.html) query does. The filters are not applied to filter data, but to give a specific score to the documents that match them. Therefore, it's normal that elasticsearch gives you all those documents back. Their scores will be computed based on the filters that you provided.

If you only want to filter your documents you need to use [normal filters](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/filter.html).
The elasticsearch [query DSL](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/) provides a lot of options for filters too (jsut look at the bottom of the page). Have a look for example at the [bool filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-filter.html) to combine multiple filters.

Comment: normal filters are not working when i need more than one filter. do u have any query which uses more than one filter?